# Setting Up New WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, virtual-directory

I'm going to add a WebAPI project to a solution in our Development branch of code. I want the web app to be published to a virtual directory "X" under the new web app located here:

```
http://website/X
```

What configurations do I need to set up in the Development environment to make this happen on the build server?

Comment: How do you plan to publish you Web API? Quick publish? Continuous integration?

Comment: Continuous integration.